# convert string to method

Tags: ruby, parsing, methods, string-parsing

I have a string that can be '+', '-', '*' or '/', and two numbers. I need to apply the operation denoted by the string to the numbers. I tried:

```
op = '+'
(&op.to_sym).call 1, 2
```

but it won't parse it. please help.

Comment: what u doing with an & ?? that is for blocks! the answer below works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby is not a Polish notation language.

```
1.send(op, 2)
```